# using parameter as argument to netsh in powershell

Tags: powershell, netsh

I am tring to change the IP address with netsh within a script. I get the error: "parameter is incorrect"
This is the script:

```
$ManagmentAddress = '192.168.11.130'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $OldName -ScriptBlock {netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet0" static $ManagmentAddress 255.255.0.0 } -Credential $Creds
```

If I change the command to use actual value instead of the argument like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $OldName -ScriptBlock {netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet0" static 192.168.11.130 255.255.0.0 } -Credential $Creds
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `param()` block for **ScripBlock** with corresponding `-ArgumentList` value.

```
$ManagmentAddress = '192.168.11.130'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $OldName -ScriptBlock {param($ManagmentAddress) netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet0" static $ManagmentAddress 255.255.0.0 } -Credential $Creds -ArgumentList $ManagmentAddress
```